# The argument type 'List<Categories>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Categories>'

Tags: api, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Here's my model class Categories

```
List<Categories> categoriesFromJson(String str) => List<Categories>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Categories.fromJson(x)));

String categoriesToJson(List<Categories> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Categories {
  Categories({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.parentId,
    this.slug,
    this.position,
    this.status,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  int parentId;
  String slug;
  int position;
  int status;

  factory Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Categories(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    parentId: json["parent_id"],
    slug: json["slug"],
    position: json["position"],
    status: json["status"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "parent_id": parentId,
    "slug": slug,
    "position": position,
    "status": status,
  };
}
```

my apiServices

```
static Future<List<Categories>> fetchCategories() async {
String url = "/categories/all";
var response = await http.get(BASE_URL + url);
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
return categoriesFromJson(response.body).toList();
} else {
return null;
}
}
```

api calling function in my controller

```
var categoryNames = <Categories>[].obs;
void fetchCategories() async {
    try{
      isLoading(true);

      var res = await ApiServices.fetchCategories();
      if(res !=null){
        categoryNames.addAll(res);
      }
    }finally{
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

in the controller, while res in categoryNames.addAll(res) is underlined with red squizzy line and above error message is displayed. When i have used same type both for categoryNews and fetchCategories() of apiService, why i am having this error. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I tried changing 
var categoryNames = <Categories>[];
 to 
List<Categories> categoryNames = <Categories>[];
but still having same error.

Comment: Add a `.toList()` after `.map()` in `categoriesFromJson` since map returns an Iterable.

Comment: i have converted to List while returning value from api call. Also, i tried adding .toList() after .map() in categoriesFromJson method of model class, but the red squizzy line won't go.

Comment: i tried just now, but not helping...also i generated model class with the help of app.quicktype.io

Comment: Have you tried this? `Categories.fromJson(json.decode(str))`. I took a look at the code again and `List.from` and `.map()` are unnecessary.

Comment: the error is in var categoryNames = <Categories>[].obs; cast it to List<Categories> <Categories>[].obs

Comment: you mean like this,,,***List<Categories> categoriesFromJson(String str) => Categories.fromJson(json.decode(str)) ; *** i'm having error as A value of type 'Categories' can't be returned from the function 'categoriesFromJson' because it has a return type of 'List<Categories>'.

Comment: what is obs and what type

Comment: i'm using getx for state management and obs is used to notify that the value might change , i tried changing var categoryNames to List<Categories> categoryNames but things are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

try to explictly define type like this

```
List<Categories> categoryNames = [];
```

also make sure to return a List from your `.map()` add `.toList()` to the end

Comment: check the `.map()`

Comment: make it like `List<Categories>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Categories.fromJson(x)).toList())`

Comment: also, i want to inform that i generated the model class with the help of http://app.quicktype.io

Comment: print `res` ? what type is it ?

Comment: the type is List<Categories>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231877/discussion-between-prabin-maharjan-and-moaid-alrazhy).

Comment: i've sent image of terminal in chat